# Windows 8 Gridview press and hold to select + appbar commands

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, appbar

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 application in XAML/C# for touch devices and run into the following: I have a GridView where a list of items is shown which are styled as tiles. When I tap on one of these tiles, I open a different page where a detailed view of that item is shown using the following properties on the GridView:

```
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
ItemClick="itemGridView_ItemClick"
```

Now I want to mimic the behaviour Windows uses on the Start screen that when you're holding a specific tile it gets selected and the AppBar shows up and offers some commands for that specific item. The commands are always the same for each item, but obviously the items aren't. When no item is selected, the AppBar shows different commands not related to a single item. On first load of the screen nothing should be selected.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

There are probably more elegant ways of doing this but I will provide you with this way that works and then you can create it as a behaviour or whatever.

You will want to handle the Holding event on the gridview sort of like the following:

```
private void gridView_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HoldingState == HoldingState.Completed)
    {
        gridView.IsCustomising = true;
        var heldItem = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Event;
        gridView.SelectedItem = heldItem;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

NB: I have extended the out of the box gridview to show the customising style like on win 8.1
NB: The types of items in my gridview in this example are of type Event whereas yours will be whatever type you have bound

You will also obviously need to create your appbar and bindup through your viewmodel what commands are visible when an item is selected in the gridview.

Hope that helps.